# Expanding a div (a box) with a header and a hidden div

Tags: javascript, html, css, expand

I'm trying to expand a box (a div) with a header and a hidden div. The problem is that the height isn't affected in the expansion and the hidden text doesn't show up properly.

The main goal is to expand a small box as if it was a tab, to a form, without changing page and with an expansion animation. When expanded, the user can see the text and edit it. As if it was something like a pop-up filling almost the entire screen. All this is already done expect the "expansion part".

I've tried to adapt my code to many of online solutions, but most of them are simple divs. This is a simple example of what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/xcWge/14/ (its only the blue box).

**HTML**

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 to-expand">
                <div id="child" class="widget">
                    <div class="widget-body text-center">
                        <div class="big-icon m-b-md watermark"><i class="fa fa-5x fa-exclamation-circle"></i></div>
                        <h2 class="m-b-md">Tarif</h2>
                        <p class="text-muted m-b-lg">Some introduction.</p>
                        <div class="menu-separator"><hr></div>
                        <div id="hidden-box">    
                          <p>This contains the text to be hidden, assume that it has a huge number of paragraphs</p>
                        </div>                                 
                        <a href="#" class="btn p-v-xl btn-primary-w" onclick="func()">Button</a>
```

.row is the group of "expandable boxes";   .to-expand is the div that includes a single box and #child is the div that included all the content in the box.

**CSS**

```
<style>
.btn-primary-w {
    border-color: #06285e;
    border-width: 2px;
}

div.to-expand {
    width: 100%;
    max-height:-10%;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: all .3s ease;
}
.to-expand.fullscreen {
    z-index: 999;
    max-height: 990px;
}
```

I saw a solution that was using a negative margin-top and then return it to 0 with overflow hidden to simulate the hidden text but that solution didn't work.

**JS**

```
function func() {
    $('#to-expand').toggleClass('fullscreen');
    $('#to-expand')[0].style.zIndex = "999";
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a visual example of the result that you would like to achieve?